# Change label text (characters) with a timer in a way to create animation?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, animation, windows-forms-designer

There's a font that has a Windows 8 style progressring in itself as characters. However, there's too many of them and programming them one by each would take forever. Is there a way I could get a label to change it's text to those characters using a timer, but without having to program each character one by one? (The font is used in both the Windows boot screen, and the Windows 8-10 Media Creation Tool to display the progressring, I would imagine there's a way to do this in C# WinForms as well.)

Here's the font file opened in charmap:

[The font with the progressring in charmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELGbH.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: You need a Timer, you need a counter (which can double as the code point of the current character), and you need to set the label text. All three of those are actually not that hard, unless you never wrote a line of code in your life. So which part do you have trouble with?

Comment: It can be done, but why reinvent the wheel - it would be much easier if you use animated Gif for that.

Comment: 1. Ah right, I haven't thought about that. I was trying to copy and paste the characters from charmap, I just remember that there's an actual code for each character point. Thanks!
2. Because Windows Forms doesn't really seem to like GIFs, and the speed the GIF plays at in WinForms applications seem to be inconsistent. One time it's smooth, one time it lags.

Comment: First: make code to "increase" the character each time you press a button. Second: make code to use a timer to change the text of a label everytime it ticks. Third: Join these two and voila! you have your solultion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this worked: (this is for the Setup font file, if you are using the C:\Windows\Boot\Fonts\segoe_slboot.ttf font file, look in charmap for the character code points)

```
char code = "\ue052"[0]; // U+E052 is the first character of the progressring

public Application()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            progressringLabel.Text = code;
        }

private void progressringTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            code++;
            progressring.Text = code.ToString();
            if (code == "\ue0CB"[0])
            {
                code = "\ue052"[0]; // When the code ends up being the last progressring character, revert back to the first one so that it won't go into the other characters
            }
        }
```